# CASE in MSSQL WHERE clause - odbc error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc, case

In my PHP web application I am trying to perfect logic that, a user-defined value, assembles a Transact-SQL query which filters on that value. The query is then executed using the ODBC driver. The complication is that the filtering will only be done on derived fields. This is working absolutely fine except for when the derived field is a field created using a CASE expression.

So, for example, I have a derived field such as the following:

```
CASE WHEN [text_result] IS NOT NULL THEN [text_result] ELSE
    CASE WHEN [last_event] = 1 THEN 'processed' ELSE 'unprocessed' END
END
```

If I try and filter this using the value "unprocessed" then the final assembled query is obviously something akin to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    CASE WHEN [text_result] IS NOT NULL THEN [text_result] ELSE
        CASE WHEN [last_event] = 1 THEN 'processed' ELSE 'unprocessed' END
    END = 'unprocessed'
```

However when this runs I receive the following error:

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'., SQL state 37000 in SQLDescribeParameter in
```

I have tried running SQL profiler and found that it appears to be that the error is being thrown during the initial statement preparation, and that the statement preparation SQL appars to be truncating the expression from the field name. So it looks like this:

```
SET FMTONLY ON select  CASE WHEN [text_result] from table where 1=2 SET FMTONLY OFF go
```

This is confirmed when I run the generated SQL statement through MSSQL management studio and it works fine!

I hope that all makes sense. If anyone has any advice as to if this problem is solvable or if it is just a bug in the driver that would be great!

This is the PHP I am using to run the assembled query (extracted out of a class):

```
$link = odbc_connect($strConnectionString,$username,$password);
$rResult = odbc_prepare($link,$qry);
$success = odbc_execute($rResult,$parameters);
```

var_dump($qry,$parameters):

```
string 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
        CASE WHEN [text_result] IS NOT NULL THEN [text_result] ELSE
            CASE WHEN [last_event] = 1 THEN 'processed' ELSE 'unprocessed' END
        END = ?'
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'unprocessed'
```

Comment: Show your php blahblah.

Comment: Please run `var_dump($qry, $parameters)` right before the code you've shared.

Comment: Your  second case statement omits WHEN.

Comment: Have you tried using the more standard syntax of "AS [Unprocessed]" to give your computed column a name?  CASE WHEN blah blah END AS [ColumnName] is the preferred syntax.  I don't know if that's messing you up, but it might be.

Comment: Var_dumps added. And @ron tomambe sorry that was my bad, mistake in copying not in code.

Comment: @pmbAustin I've tried declaring it with an alias in the SELECT expression and then filtering on the alias, but I simply get an error that the field name is not valid. I have also tried adding `AS [Unprocessed]` in the WHERE clause and it makes no difference.

Comment: FYI the assembled query **works fine when run with management studio**

Comment: I agree this is an ODBC problem. You may try placing parentheses around the outer case statement.

Comment: Ok at least I'm not crazy. I've tried adding parenthesis with no luck I'm afraid...

Comment: Do you have a table called table?Also try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: Have you tried putting the query in a CTE expression instead, and then selecting from that?  I wonder if that would work. Basically this:  WITH myQuery AS (...put your entire select statement here...) SELECT columns FROM myQuery;

Comment: Last time I got ODBC errors from SQL Server it was because SQL Server was ignoring the max packet size when sending large volumes of text, thus causing ODBC to reject packets and causing the whole connection to fail. It might be worth trying to increase your max packet size, and/or casting your text_result column to a reduced size (`CAST(text_result AS VARCHAR(2000)`).

Comment: Thanks I'll try anything. Where would I put that CAST expression? Would I wrap the entire CASE..END expression in it?

Comment: **More news** : If I don't use the parameter, but instead push the variable directly in, then it does not fail. e.g. `WHERE CASE ... END = 'foo'`

Comment: This works: `qry= new MSSQLQuery("SELECT 'hello' 
WHERE
'foo' =
(
 CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
)");`. This doesn't: `qry= new MSSQLQuery("SELECT 'hello' 
WHERE
(
 CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
) = ?","foo");`

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't need nested `case` statements.  You can just do:

```
CASE WHEN [text_result] IS NOT NULL THEN [text_result] 
     WHEN [last_event] = 1 THEN 'processed' 
     ELSE 'unprocessed'
END
```

One thing that I see wrong with your `select` is the `=`.  You can write:

```
SELECT unprocessed = (CASE WHEN [text_result] IS NOT NULL THEN [text_result] 
                           WHEN [last_event] = 1 THEN 'processed' 
                           ELSE 'unprocessed'
                      END)
```

or

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN [text_result] IS NOT NULL THEN [text_result] 
             WHEN [last_event] = 1 THEN 'processed' 
             ELSE 'unprocessed'
        END) as unprocessed
```

But, when using `=`, the variable comes first.

Then, I don't think you can specify a column alias using `?`.  You have to construct the query string with the column alias name in it.

Comment: The ? is the placeholder for the user input as passed in by a prepared statement, not a column alias? So should the ? come first (making the result "...WHERE 'unprocessed' = (CASE..)")?

Comment: @user1014679 . . . That is what I meant.  I don't think you can specify a column alias as a parameter in a prepared statement.

Comment: @user1014679 . . . Your sample code as `END = 'unprocessed'` which suggests that you want to use `unprocessed` as an alias.

Comment: Ok I don't, it's a user input value. What is your definition of an alias?

Comment: I thought I was doing a comparison in my code, but if I am actually making an alias somehow could you enlighten me as to how to do a comparison? I want to see if the value resolved by the CASE expression is equal to the value passed in by the user

Comment: This works: `qry= new MSSQLQuery("SELECT 'hello' 
WHERE
'foo' =
(
 CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
)");`. This doesn't: `qry= new MSSQLQuery("SELECT 'hello' 
WHERE
(
 CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
) = ?","foo");`

Comment: @user1014679 . . . I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to convey.  The query that doesn't work is not valid SQL.

Comment: That's the php - for some reason the comment strips out the $. They're both identical except the second one is parameterised.

Comment: but if php is replacing the ? with foo in your string, your sql string will be missing quotes. Try ... = '?'", "foo");

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `case` stataments:

```
DECLARE  @tableA Table
(
    text_result varchar(20),
    last_event int
)

INSERT INTO @tableA
VALUES
    (null, 1),
    (null, 2),
    ('xxxx', 3)

SELECT *
FROM @tableA
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN text_result IS NOT NULL THEN text_result  
         WHEN last_event = 1 THEN 'processed' 
    ELSE 'unprocessed' END = 'unprocessed'
```

Comment: The same problem occurs if I remove the nested case statement (e.g. `...WHERE CASE WHEN text_result IS NOT NULL THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END = ?`)

Comment: This works: `qry= new MSSQLQuery("SELECT 'hello' 
WHERE
'foo' =
(
 CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
)");`. This doesn't: `qry= new MSSQLQuery("SELECT 'hello' 
WHERE
(
 CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END
) = ?","foo");`

Comment: See my comment on the previous answer, I believe that you are missing quotes around the ?.